# Automatically filter/limit questions to favorite tags

Tags: support, feature-request, tag-watching

Is there a way (by default) to filter/limit the questions that I see on the Stack Overflow [Home page](https://stackoverflow.com) to just my favorite tags?

I don't want to add an "ignore tag" for every topic I don't want to see and I would prefer not to enter search terms every time.

Comment: Use an advanced search `intags:mine is:question`.  I don't know how to default this on homepage behavior.

Comment: By and large I've noticed that my favorite tagged questions show up more prominently on the main page feed. I do have a lot of favorite tags and they're in fairly popular tags, so... Which tags are you favoring, and are they relatively active?

Comment: My tags are very active (C, C++, C#), but I see posts from too many topics that I have no expertise and in many cases no real interest.  Actually, I have interest in MANY things, but too many things to learn and too little time.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer that to *not* be the default, i like the home page results as-is, where it shows mostly things that i browse often and my favorited tags, and then a few things that are outside that list for variety.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can build tag search URL from favorite tags and save it in bookmarks in your browser. For example this URL will search questions tagged by at least one of top 3 tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+java+or+c%23.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that might be the best solution.  I'm surprised that this is not by default, I would have though most would want it that way.   Especially with so many varied topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt into the [Custom Views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer?cb=1) feature lets you do this, I believe.  You can opt in from the settings in your user profile.

The setting notes

> We are gradually enabling this feature to users who opt in. You may not see changes reflected immediately.

I enabled this for my profile a about a week ago but have yet to see the tools appear.  Doubtless it takes about [6 - 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/397555) to take effect.